# Sorting join layer based on attribute column?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, sorting

Im joining dots with a CSV file and map my data with proportional circles. Unfortunately I have some overlapping.

How do I sort a join layer based on attribute column called *aPOPCLA72* ?

- Filtering virtual layer of my layer based on `1=1 order by "aPOPCLA72" desc` do not work. The column is not sorted.
- Sorting using MMQGIS gives me invalid sort field name error (field name: aPOPCLA72)

Why I want to sort my data: avoiding proportional circles overlapping. I want to render the big circles first.

[image]

I am using QGIS 3.6

Comment: the suggestion below to use the 'control feature rendering order' will only work if your data is NOT joined, that is, if you export your joined datasets into a static one... I've been having this issue lately.

Answer (score 4):

Try controlling drawing order within symbology menu:

[image]

*Note this is just a workaround to get your visual result. It will not change the sort order of attributes. Only the order in which your features will be drawn.*

Comment: Thank you forhelping. Not working with the size assistant ?

Comment: Not sure if I get you right. But you can not control drawing or attribute order using size assistant.

Comment: It should actually work like you tried with virtual layer. E.g. `select * from pointlayername order by "aPOPCLA72 " desc`. Can't tell why it does not from here...

Comment: OK. It is why I want to sort my column before to ovoid overlapping. The size asssistant is great for rendering proportional symbols.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes sure, use the renderer like you already did. Just leave everything as it is and do the step in my answer as additional step.

Comment: Using virtual layer `select * from datamap order by  "aPOPCLA72" desc`  query not working. Nothing appen

Comment: Yes, I said it **should** work and I cant tell from here why it does not. Back on topic: does it work via `layer rendering` as additioinal step like in my answer?

Comment: No working with layer rendering. No effect (ascending or descending)